# Can't receive tap events on google maps widget flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

Here's the code that I have so far

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class TempView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TempView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TempView> createState() => _TempViewState();
}

class _TempViewState extends State<TempView> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller =
      Completer<GoogleMapController>();

  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  static const CameraPosition _kLake = CameraPosition(
      bearing: 192.8334901395799,
      target: LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792),
      tilt: 59.440717697143555,
      zoom: 19.151926040649414);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        onTap: (argument) => print("tapped"),
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _goToTheLake,
        label: const Text('To the lake!'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _goToTheLake() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_kLake));
  }
}
```

It's the same as the code on the pub.dev page for the `google_maps_flutter` widget, except I added an `onTap`.

For some reason the `onTap` never fires! I've even tried adding custom gesture recognisers into the `gestureRecognizers` set, like the `EagerGestureRecognizer` and the `TapGestureRecognizer`.

I'm on Flutter 3.7 macOS with Apple M1.

Why isn't it working, and how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap GoogleMap widget with InkWell Widget and use its property of onTap, it will work.

InkWell(
onTap: () => ,
child:
),

Comment: But I need the LatLng tapped

Comment: Hello, you can use formatting on StackOverflow to make your answer easier to read. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it seems to run just fine. tapped gets printed every time i tap on map.

Please make sure your tap is in GoogleMap region and that no other widget is overlaying if this isn’t the whole code.